# How to make a variable seen in layout?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have model **User** with relationship:

```
belongs_to :freelancer
```

and model **Freelancer** with:

```
belongs_to :user.
```

For registration use **Devise**.
After registration a new user is automatically created Freelancer object with `user_id = current user.id`.  How better way me get `@freelancer` object with `user_id = current user`  after *sign up* or *sign in* and pass in  layout template:

**layouts/_user_panel.html.erb**

```
<div class="user-panel_head">
    <%= link_to @freelancer, title: current_user.username, class: "user-panel__avatar active" do %>
      <%= image_tag "default/avatar.png", class: "avatario" %>
    <% end %>
    <div class="user-panel__side">
      <%= link_to current_user.username,  @freelancer, class: "user-panel__user-name" %>
      <span class="btn_drop icon_arrow_up" role="expand_menu_trigger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

UPDATE:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: users
#
#  id                     :integer          not null, primary key
#  email                  :string           default(""), not null
#  encrypted_password     :string           default(""), not null
#  reset_password_token   :string
#  reset_password_sent_at :datetime
#  remember_created_at    :datetime
#  sign_in_count          :integer          default(0), not null
#  current_sign_in_at     :datetime
#  last_sign_in_at        :datetime
#  current_sign_in_ip     :string
#  last_sign_in_ip        :string
#  created_at             :datetime         not null
#  updated_at             :datetime         not null
#  confirmation_token     :string
#  confirmed_at           :datetime
#  confirmation_sent_at   :datetime
#  unconfirmed_email      :string
#  failed_attempts        :integer          default(0), not null
#  unlock_token           :string
#  locked_at              :datetime
#  username               :string
#
# Indexes
#
#  index_users_on_confirmation_token    (confirmation_token) UNIQUE
#  index_users_on_email                 (email) UNIQUE
#  index_users_on_reset_password_token  (reset_password_token) UNIQUE
#  index_users_on_unlock_token          (unlock_token) UNIQUE
#

class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  belongs_to :freelancer
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable, :lockable
end
```

**FREELANCER MODEL**

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: freelancers
#
#  id             :integer          not null, primary key
#  first_name     :string
#  last_name      :string
#  rate           :integer
#  birthday       :date
#  location       :string
#  description    :text
#  site           :string
#  visible        :boolean
#  avatar         :string
#  category_id    :integer
#  created_at     :datetime         not null
#  updated_at     :datetime         not null
#  user_id        :integer
#  specialization :string
#  price_category :string
#  ownership      :string
#
# Indexes
#
#  index_freelancers_on_category_id  (category_id)
#  index_freelancers_on_user_id      (user_id)
#

class Freelancer < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :category  
   belongs_to :user
   has_many :links
   has_and_belongs_to_many :payment_options

   accepts_nested_attributes_for :links, allow_destroy: true

   PRICE_CATEGORIES = ['Project', 'Hour', 'Month', 'For 1000 characters']
   OWNERSHIP_TYPES = ['Individual', 'Company']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one, It will create `Freelancer` right after `sign_up`.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :freelancer, dependent: :destroy
   before_create :set_freelancer

   def set_freelancer
    build_freelancer(id: self.id, user_id: self.id, email: self.email)
   end 
end

class Freelancer < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :user
end
```

Comment: if you had trouble with it, just fixed now should be working. also good point of this, User and freelancer ids will be the same always.

Answer (score 1):

What's the difference between `current_user` and `@freelancer` in this example? You're populating your view with data from `current_user` which implies they're the same object, so couldn't you just `link_to current_user, ...`?

Anyhow, to address the point of your question -- instance variables in the controller get passed to layouts just as they do to templates and partials. They're all considered views and generally behave in a similar fashion. Thus, you would need to set `@freelancer` in the controller within whatever action is responsible for rendering your page.

In the case of Devise, you should consider overriding the `after_sign_up_path_for` method and return the route you want the user to be redirected to after registration.

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  # Resource is a User in this case
  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      super(resource)

      user_path(resource)  # Return the path for the `users#show` route
    end
  end
end
```

So you'd assign `@freelancer` in the controller action associated with `user_path`. The same principle would apply to Devise's `SessionsController`